# Java spring portlet extends GenericPortlet how to autowire dependencies

Tags: java, spring, portlet, liferay-6

I am using java - spring - portlet

I want to keep using my portlet as extend to GenericPortlet but i want to use spring dependency injections.

Currently i found the work around which is as follows instead i want to autoWire AccountsDao dependency. Can somebody help me out that how can i autowire when my portlet extends GenericPortlet and not @Controller

```
public class HelloPortlet extends GenericPortlet {

@ProcessAction(name = "searchAccount") 
    public void listAllAccounts(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

ApplicationContext springCtx = PortletApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(getPortletContext());
        AccountsDao dao  = (AccountsDao)springCtx.getBean("accountsDao");
}

}
```

Comment: why don't you place @Controller over your class definition? What happens if you do so? How did you try to connect this class to your spring context (in your application-context.xml? If so, please post the relevant lines)

Comment: i do not wants to use @Controller b/c i found that genericPortlet implementation is much easy and user friendly ? what you think ?

Comment: why don't you combine them?

Comment: combine them like class having @Controller annotation and extends GenericPortlet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to configure and enable spring based controllers to acheive this instead of extending to GenericPortlet...